# HDFS NameNode JvmPauseMonitor waring caused by cloudera manager agent

Tags: hadoop, jvm, cloudera-cdh

In our online cluster, we got lots of such warning:

```
2020-01-21 09:08:00,711 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.JvmPauseMonitor: Detected pause in JVM or host machine (eg GC): pause of approximately 2328ms
No GCs detected
```

As it showed, there is no GC, but jvm just paused.

We noticed that the waring happens every 1 minute, and when such warning happens, cpu usage of cmf-agent increase to 80%. So we try shutdown cmf-agent,  after cmf-agent is down, the waring just gone.

We have disabled Cloudera Manager jstack monitoring, what else cloudera managager agent do will cause jvm pause?

we are using CDH 5.4.14.

Edit at 2020-01-22:

```
/usr/java/default/bin/java -Dproc_namenode -Xmx1000m -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,RFAAUDIT -Dsecurity.audit.logger=INFO,RFAS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop-hdfs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop-cmf-hdfs-NAMENODE-1350.log.out -Dhadoop.home.dir=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.14.4-1.cdh5.14.4.p0.3/lib/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=hdfs -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,RFA -Djava.library.path=/opt/cloudera/parcels/GPLEXTRAS-5.14.4-1.cdh5.14.4.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.14.4-1.cdh5.14.4.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms210453397504 -Xmx210453397504 -Xmn24g -XX:SurvivorRatio=2 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:CMSFullGCsBeforeCompaction=0 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=0 -verbose:GC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:+PrintClassHistogramAfterFullGC -XX:+PrintClassHistogramBeforeFullGC -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=200M -Xloggc:/var/log/hadoop-hdfs/nn.gc.log -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/usr/lib64/cmf/service/common/killparent.sh -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
```

Comment: What are the JVM Options based to those processes?

Comment: Hi @cricket_007,  I have added full jvm options, please take a look